# How to paste to Emacs from clipboard on OSX?

Tags: emacs, osx-lion, paste, emacs22

This might be extraordinarily simple, but I am playing with Emacs (22.1.1) and I can't get it to paste text in the clipboard using <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd>.

Comment: Using evil (simulating vim-like behaviour), I use this trick: `:r!xsel` or `:r!xsel -b` what reads output of command specified after exclamation mark. On MacOS you would probably use `pbaste`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you're using the in-built Emacs, then you're running Emacs in the terminal.  The "clipboard" is a function of your windowing system.  Emacs in terminal mode (`-nw`) does not access any windowing system specific APIs.  This is true of most command line tools designed to work in the terminal.

You need to upgrade your Emacs as others have suggested, and run in graphical
mode.  Using Emacs 24 on Mac OS X, the behaviour you want is the default.

If you want to do this in a terminal, then [this](http://allkindsofrandomstuff.blogspot.de/2009/09/sharing-mac-clipboard-with-emacs.html) hack will make the clipboard work.

```
(defun copy-from-osx ()
(shell-command-to-string "pbpaste"))

(defun paste-to-osx (text &optional push)
(let ((process-connection-type nil))
(let ((proc (start-process "pbcopy" "*Messages*" "pbcopy")))
(process-send-string proc text)
(process-send-eof proc))))

(setq interprogram-cut-function 'paste-to-osx)
(setq interprogram-paste-function 'copy-from-osx)
```

Comment: Perfect answer. One quick comment though: if I upgrade my Emacs and then use the -nw to run it in the terminal, will I be able to use the system clipboard? Or I need to use the hack if I want to work in the terminal regardless of the Emacs version?

Comment: Terminal applications can't access the system clipboard.  The hack isn't so bad though, I do use `pbcopy` in other contexts.

Comment: I use Emacs 24.1 but can't paste to emacs from clipboard even if I use  graphical mode.

Comment: the link provided seems faulty.. I get to a site with no content.

Comment: [Here](http://allkindsofrandomstuff.blogspot.de/2009/09/sharing-mac-clipboard-with-emacs.html) is the same or a similar link.

Comment: The beginning of this answer is inaccurate: I access the system clipboard from Vim in the terminal all the time. There's no reason a terminal application can't interact with the system clipboard. `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` are, after all, processs running in the terminal themselves.

Comment: @Peeja Your perception of what's running "in terminal" is not correct.  You can launch an executable from the terminal that runs in your windowing system.  You can launch "Finder" form a terminal, does that mean it's "running in terminal"?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm talking about at all. I run Vim within tmux, within iTerm. It uses my system clipboard as the `*` register. Any running executable can access that clipboard, if the authors have used the API for it.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I've changed the answer to reflect your point.

Comment: @event_jr: To get your copy-from-osx hack to work, I had to add (interactive) to the defun. I didn't need paste-to-osx -- command-C copies whatever I highlight. Also, it seems to me you've named the functions in reverse -- your copy-from-osx pastes into the emacs buffer while paste-to-osx copies text into the clipboard for a subsequent paste operation.

Comment: Can I also apply it for Linux systems? How can I run emacs in `graphical mode`?  @event_jr

Answer (score 49):

Try using the `M-x clipboard-yank` command. If you want to copy text to the clipboard you have to `M-x clipboard-kill-region`.

This works on Linux and Windows, I guess on Mac it's the same.

Comment: I actually tried this at work today on my Ubuntu 11.10 using the lastest emacs and it did not work. It says the kill ring is empty. I am using your first command.

Comment: Brilliant! I am running emacs 24.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 and connecting via Windows 7 using XWin Server and this pulled the contents from my Windows clipboard into my emacs session. Thanks!

Comment: Confirming that this does work on a Mac -- using OS X 10.8.5 and Emacs 24.3. I did not test this with Aquamacs.

Comment: this works on debian, emacs 24.10. The accepted answer wont work here.

Comment: The `clipboard-yank` broken at least in Emacs-25.0 — in the presence of `select-enable-clipboard` set to «nil» does not anymore works with clipboard. On the other hand I guess that could be a bugfix, cuz the docs clearly says, that the function may paste last killed text as well. But in fact I doesn't see a way now to disable clipboard contaminating, and yet be able to use it's content.

Comment: brilliant answer, works on ubuntu 14.04 lts with emacs 24

Answer (score 19):

I usually use Shift+insert to paste into an emacs buffer, I don't know if your keyboard has those keys though.

Comment: Yeah it does not. Although I am beginner, I am surprised to find this difficult to do.

Comment: try the yank command, just do M-x yank. To see the keychord that runs this command on your system you may run C-h w yank

Comment: if this still doesn't work, you may want to check the cua-mode

Answer (score 1):

That's strange.

I use command-V, and it works every time.

When you focus on the terminal window, anything you paste through command-V becomes separate keystrokes sent into the terminal.

I use Mac OS X 10.5 (Leopard) and emacs 22.1.1.

Comment: It seems the user has already resolved his issue though, by updating his Emacs. Also, the user wasn't using command-V, but C-y (which is the default command for "yanking" in Emacs).

Answer (score 1):

See http://blog.binchen.org/?p=589

Here is code:

```
(require 'simpleclip)
(defun copy-to-clipboard ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((thing (if (region-active-p)
                   (buffer-substring-no-properties (region-beginning) (region-end))
                 (thing-at-point 'symbol))))
    (simpleclip-set-contents thing)
    (message "thing => clipboard!")))

(defun paste-from-clipboard()
  "Paste string clipboard"
  (interactive)
  (insert (simpleclip-get-contents)))
```

The code use simpleclip (https://github.com/rolandwalker/simpleclip)

Simpleclip requires you install some command line tool on Mac/Linux/Cygwin which . So even emacs without graphic support could also access clipboard.

This solution works on any version of Emacs, any OS. It also works when your remote ssh if the server enables X forward, the complete command is `ssh -X -C -c blowfish-cbc,arcfour name@host.com`)

Comment: Isn't this answer restricted to X11, in which case it does not work with  macOS-native versions of emacs?

Answer (score 0):

On `Windows`? I have `M-ins` bound to `h-insert-x-selection`, which I have defined as follows:

```lisp
(defun h-insert-x-selection () (interactive)
  (insert (x-selection 'CLIPBOARD))) 
(global-set-key [(meta insert)] 'h-insert-x-selection)
```

On `XEmacs` it is different, where I have

```lisp
(global-set-key  [(shift insert)] 'x-insert-selection)
```

Comment: Did I mention I was a beginner? :) So you would have to do a key mapping for a simple paste?

Comment: I needed key mapping on Windows. I don't know about Max OSX, but if `C-y` is not doing it for you this seems easiest.

Answer (score 0):

OS suse 12.2 - emacs default version 24.2-15.8.2 (x86_64) just ignored pasting from clipboard by ctrl-y
Finally problem resolved by down grade to version 23.3-15.5.1 (x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [pbcopy.el](https://melpa.org/#/pbcopy). I was using Doom Emacs.

To install it, run

1. `M-x package-install`
2. Press the return key
3. provide `pbcopy.el` as the package to install
4. Press the return key
5. inside your config file, add:

```lisp
(require 'pbcopy)
(turn-on-pbcopy)
```

6. restart emacs

I also had tried using [clipetty](https://melpa.org/#/clipetty) and [simpleclip](https://melpa.org/#/simpleclip) which did not work for me.